# Git rebase --onto: atal: Needed a single revision

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

When trying to rebase a feature branch onto master, I get the following error:

The situation I'm in is almost exactly the situation described in the manual where it talks about transplanting a topic onto master.

```
o---o---o---o---o  master
     \
     o---o---o---o---o  next (telephony)
                  \
                   o---o---o  topic (ivr)
```

The situation is slightly different in that next has already been merged into master.

I want to transplant ivr onto master, but when I do I get the error:

```
dhcp-156:gitrepos barry$ git rebase --onto origin/master telelphony ivr
fatal: Needed a single revision
invalid upstream telelphony
```

Which looks like it can't find the telephony branch?

Comment: For me, it does see telephony but the way you used is wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want the `telephony` branch you need to say `telephony`, not `telelphony`.

Comment: oh boy. I'm going to leave this question here like a cone of shame.

Comment: @StuartGrimshaw: It's a well known fact that typos are a lot easier to spot once you've posted them to the internet.

Comment: Yes, *please* leave this post around!  I also had a typo (language vs langauge) and couldn't see it.  This is the only place I found on the web where this error was linked with "typo".